# Como obter de um caminho a data e extensão de um arquivo utilizando alguma função do PHP

Tags: php, html, html5

Tenho um array com dois tipos de arquivos: `.jpg` e `.pdf`. Estou desenvolvendo uma página em PHP de publicações mensais.

Criei um `select` para definir o ano da publicação, o usuário poderá escolher o ano da publicação, tipo: ao escolher o ano de 2018, automaticamente
aparecerá todas as capas das publicações de cada mês do ano 2018 em um `<img>`, ao clicar na imagem da publicação gostaria que abrisse outra página
no navegador baixando o PDF da publicação.

No código a seguir, consigo trazer do caminho todos os arquivos em `.jpg` e `.pdf`. Só não consigo desenvolver como pegar esses arquivos no array e realocar o `.jpg` na página e o `.pdf` para fazendo download.

Código:

```
<center>
<div>
    <h3>Publicações</h3>
        <div>
            <form id="formConsulta" action="arquivo.php" method="post" name="formConsulta">
                <select name="slcAnoFalaBrt">
                    <option value='2012'>2012</option>
                    <option value='xxx'>xxx</option>
                   <option value='2019'>2019</option>
               </select>
                <input type="submit" value="Buscar">
            </form>
        </div>
        <br>
        <div>

        </div>
</div>




<?php

if(isset($_POST['slcAno'])){

$intAno = $_POST['slcAno'];

//Obter a listagem dos Arquivos do diretório
$pasta = 'download/Publicacoes/';


if(is_dir($pasta)){
  $diretorio = dir($pasta);
  //var_dump($diretorio);//

  while($arquivo = $diretorio->read()){
    if($arquivo != '..' && $arquivo != '.'){
        // Cria um Array com todos os Arquivos encontrados
    $arrayArquivos[date('Y/m/d H:i:s', filemtime($pasta.$arquivo))] =   $pasta.$arquivo;


    }//fim if//
    }//fim while//

  $diretorio->close();
}//fim if is_dir();//

//Classificar os  arquivos para a Ordem Crescente
//krsort($arrayArquivos, SORT_STRING);

//Mostra a listagem dos Arquivos
foreach($arrayArquivos as $valorArquivos ){

echo '<a href='.$valorArquivos.'>'.$valorArquivos.'</a><br />';//


}//fim foreach

}//fim if isset//

?>
```

Comment: Caros, não sei deixar o código formatado no padrão do Stack overflow! Alguém poderia ajudar!

Comment: PCP84, no editor existe duas chaves {}, selecione o seu código e clique nele. :)

Comment: Formatei o código. Para saber como fazer, veja a [central de ajuda](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)

Comment: Porque você usa a data `date('Y/m/d H:i:s', filemtime($pasta.$arquivo))` no índice do array? E quando você usa `$intAno`?

Comment: int ano e para selecionar o ano da publicação, e date('Y/m/d H:i:s', filemtime($pasta.$arquivo)) a ideia e para comparar a data do arquivo. (se usuario selecionar ano de 2018 printar na tela somente publicações de 2018!

Answer (score 1):

Fiz algumas modificações no seu código que deve funcionar (não testei), a explicação está nos comentários do código, mas basicamente agrupei os arquivos por `mes e ano` e depois iterei em cada grupo pegando o tipo do arquivo com `pathinfo()`.

*** As linhas marcadas com `/* ****** */` foram sofreram alguma modificação.

**EDIT:** Adicionei adicionei uma filtragem para ignorar arquivos que não são do ano desejado.

```
      <?php

    if (isset($_POST['slcAno'])) {

        $intAno = $_POST['slcAno'];
/* * */ $arrayArquivos = [];
        //Obter a listagem dos Arquivos do diretório
        $pasta = 'download/Publicacoes/';


        if (is_dir($pasta)) {
            $diretorio = dir($pasta);
            //var_dump($diretorio);//

            while ($arquivo = $diretorio->read()) {
                if ($arquivo != '..' && $arquivo != '.') {
                    // Cria um Array com todos os Arquivos encontrados
    /* ********** */ $fileTime = filemtime($pasta . $arquivo);
    /* ********** */ $fileYear = date('Y', $fileTime );
    /* ********** */ if($fileYear == $intAno){
    /* ********** */    $arrayArquivos[date('Ym', $fileTime)][] =   $pasta . $arquivo; //deve conter 1 pdf e um jpeg (que são do mesmo mes)
    /* ********** */ }
                } //fim if//
            } //fim while//

            $diretorio->close();
        } //fim if is_dir();//

        //Classificar os  arquivos para a Ordem Crescente
        //krsort($arrayArquivos, SORT_STRING);

        //Mostra a listagem dos Arquivos


        foreach ($arrayArquivos as $valorArquivos) {

    /* ****** */ $img = "";
    /* ****** */ $pdf = "";
    /* ****** */ //verifica se o caminho salvo no mes especificado é pdf ou outro
    /* ****** */ foreach($valorArquivos as $arquivo){
    /* ****** */     if(pathinfo($arquivo)['extension'] == "pdf"){
    /* ****** */         $pdf = $arquivo;
    /* ****** */     }else{
    /* ****** */         $img = $arquivo;
    /* ****** */     }
    /* ****** */ }
    /* ****** */ echo '<a href=' . $pdf . '>' . $img . '</a><br />'; //


        } //fim foreach

    }//fim if isset//
```

Comment: Não funcionou @ edson alves ! está retornando o mesmo jpg e  pdf ao selecionar qualquer ano!

Comment: A parte que mexi foi para separar pdf e jpeg. Vou alterar pra trazer apenas o ano escolhido.

Comment: Testa agora pra ver

Comment: esta dando erro na variável $arrayArquivos ( Undefined variable: arrayArquivos in /caminho...) e  Invalid argument supplied for foreach().

Comment: Qual a versão do seu php? Tenta agora, inicializei a variável `$arrayArquivos = [];`

Comment: versão Current PHP version: 7.0.30. Fiz o teste aqui e não funcionou!

Comment: Pode adicionar o erro que deu agora?

Comment: não acontece nada! A pagina carrega mas não retorna nenhuma imagem

Comment: Tenta,  estava retornando vazio pois `$fileTime == $intAno` nunca seria verdadeiro, o correto é `$fileYear == $intAno`